# CD install on white MacMini

Tags: release-juno, system-installation, boot

I am trying to get elementary OS on an old white MacMini. The machine does not boot from USB and does not have a DVD drive. I have tried a USB DVD drive but that is not recognized. Is there a way to get a lite version that fits on a CD and then add everything later?

I did have an early version of elementary OS on the machine but it never updated to the newer versions I don't know if it should so I deleted it and then found I can't install anything.

Comment: I did a bit of googling and couldn't find a model of mac mini that didn't have a dvd drive, so I'm wondering if the problem is with the disc in some way. How did you get elementary on the mac in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that there are many MAC Mini that did not have a DVD player

Mac Mini 2011 : https://support.apple.com/kb/SP632?locale=fr_FR&viewlocale=en_US

if this is a tutorial form [oemb1905](https://askubuntu.com/users/431287/oemb1905), for Ubuntu is present on this link

https://askubuntu.com/questions/885978/how-to-install-ubuntu-to-a-mac-mini-i7-2011-with-amd-graphics